# Add an image to the left/right of a NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-mountain-lion

How can I add an image to the left/right of a NSTextField?

On iOS there is a leftView, rightView property.

Comment: You can subclass the cell and draw extra content that way in the cells drawRect: for example.

Comment: Is this available now? I am also looking for this.

Comment: any sample code?